# Save Bitmap as a jpeg image

Tags: android, bitmap

In my android application i generate a qr code then save it as a jpeg image, i use this code:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
final Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("pic");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save); 
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            OutputStream fOutputStream = null;
            File file = new File(path + "/Captures/", "screen.jpg");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            try {

                fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOutputStream);

                fOutputStream.flush();
                fOutputStream.close();
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

but it always catches an exception at the line:

```
fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

what caused this problem???

Comment: whats the exception you are getting? please post the error log

Comment: Do you target API 23? Have you requested the storage permission at runtime?

Comment: FileNotFound Exception @Newbiee

Comment: Yes, i added this line in manifest:                                                                                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: it means your file is not created.. which device are you testing on? which is the android version in it?

Comment: i tested it on 4.4 and 5 android versions

Comment: Try setting Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); as path

Comment: Didn't work @Newbiee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what caused this problem???

The statement `file.mkdirs();` created a directory by the name `screen.jpg`. The `FileOutputStream` could not create a file with name `screen.jpg` while there is a directory by that name is found. So you got:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Could you please replace following snippets:

```
File file = new File(path + "/Captures/", "screen.jpg");
if (!file.exists()) {
   file.mkdirs();
}
```

by the following snippets:

```
String dirPath = path + "/Captures/";       
File dirFile = new File(dirPath);
if(!dirFile.exists()){
   dirFile.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(dirFile, "screen.jpg");
```

and see the results?